# Appropriate usage of the word "custody"

Tags: word-usage, prepositional-phrases

Is the application of the word "custody" in the following sentence correct?

> He is under the custody of his father.

Comment: These kinds of brief questions with no explanations tend to be flagged as "low quality". Please explain why you think your example does or does not make sense.

Answer (score 1):

It's not not-understandable, but the usual construction is "in the custody of", or "[custodian] has custody of [the one in custody]", e.g. "His father has custody of him".  "In the custody of" additionally implies police or similar.  "The sheriff has Hamid in custody", "Hamid is in the custody of the FBI".  Saying "Joey is in the custody of his father" would be grammatically correct, but odd-sounding because of the connotation.

Answer (score 0):

*X in custody* means X is contained and being guarded by someone else, if X is a person, it means X is arrested, detained or in jail.  Things like evidence or other valuable things in transport (money, deposits) can also be in custody of a carrier.

If you are talking about parental rights, the "custody" is something that is *had*.  So you would say "X has custody of the children" for example.

*Under custody* is not a common phrase but would likely be understood as equivalent to "X in custody" above.  The Google Ngram for *under custody* shows this phrase was much more common a century ago.